# chi squared test R and excel

Tags: r, excel, statistics, chi-squared

I'm working on independence testing for some stuff at work. I'm usually do this sort of thing in R, but my boss wanted me to do it in Excel for the graphs. My problem is that when I use R's chi squared test, it gives me a different result from the one Excel uses. I'm not sure if I'm setting things up wrong, or if there's a difference in methods used, but the results are pretty much polar opposites. Are the null hypotheses different in these two programs?

Here's what I've got:

```
Observed Values                     Expected Values     

    Total Errors    Priority 1 + 2                  Total Errors    Priority 1 + 2
Non-V&T 342 188 530         Non-V&T 171.0759494 93.92405063
V&T 117 64  181         V&T 58.42405063 32.07594937
    459 252 1422                    


    Test value:                         
    2.68619E-79
```

R:

```
tbl1 <- matrix(c(342,117,188,64),ncol=2)
chisq.test(tbl1)
Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  tbl1
X-squared = 1.6653e-30, df = 1, p-value = 1

chisq.test(tbl1)$expected
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 342.1519 187.8481
[2,] 116.8481  64.1519
```

ps. I can't seem to paste in what I had from Excel properly. The main point is that the p-value expected values are different from what R gives me.

Answer (score 3):

I too am not sure how to paste from Excel at the moment, but I can provide you with the formulas I used in Excel via a screenshot. It produced a p-value of 0.9782, close to that given in R. Please see the following screenshot for the values:

[image]

1. In the above, I use the actual values as input into R. Cells A2:B3
2. I compute the marginal row and column sums
3. I compute the expected cell values by taking a product of the appropriate marginal row and column sum, and dividing by the overall sum. Cells A7:B8
4. I compute the p-value next using the actual and expected counts.

If you re-do the R procedure without the Yates correction, i.e `chisq.test(tbl1, correct = F)`, you get a p-value of 0.9782, which corresponds to Excel's p-value.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had calculated the expected values incorrectly because I added the wrong numbers together to get n.